# How do I reconnect my Firebase instance so that I can read and write?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using the diagnostic `checkConnectionStatus()` method provided in the `Firebase` documentation, I'm seeing in the log that my `Firebase` instance is not connected to its server.

My read/write rules are both set as true, and checking `DatabaseReference` values in the debugger, the `database` URL is correct. I've also tried using multiple WiFi connections to ensure that this issue wasn't as a result of any firewall settings.

This particular `fragment` was perfectly functional until this problem arose out of nowhere and it isn't obvious to me how to fix it!

My app level dependencies for `Firebase` are:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
```

The diagnostic method provided in the Firebase documentation, returning false, is:

```
 private void checkConnectionStatus(){
        DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance          ().getReference(".info/connected");
        connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
                if (connected) {
                    Log.d("Status", "connected");
                } else {
                    Log.d("Status", "not connected");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Log.w("Uh oh", "Listener was cancelled");
            }
        });
    }
```

My read/write rules are:

```
    {
     "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
     }
  }
```

I used `Firebase` in another project and never encountered this issue, so I am at a loss in terms of what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: did you tried to import the database dependency ?

Comment: Sorry -- I did, but the post wasn't formatted correctly. It's in bold instead of in the code section! I'll try and fix that rn